# How to substitute a variable in an expression in haskell?

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

I'm working with the lambda calculus implemented in haskell. Expressions:

```
%x.e  -- lambda abstraction, like \x->e in Haskell
e e'  -- application
x,y,z -- variables
succ, pred, ifzero, 0, 1, 2....
```

Syntax:

```
type Id = String

-- The "builtin" functions.
data Op = Succ | Pred | IfZero
       deriving (Show, Ord, Eq)

-- Expressions of L
data Exp = Var Id
     | Nat Integer
     | Op Op
     | Lam Id Exp
     | App Exp Exp
       deriving (Ord, Eq, Show)
```

There's also a function that converts the usual representation into `Exp`:

```
    parse "%f. f 1 2" = Lam "f" App (App (Var "f") (Nat 1)) (Nat 2)`
```

And I have to write the function `subst x e e'` that will substitute `e` for all "free" occurrences of `(Var x)` in `e'`. "Free" means that the variable it is not declared by a surrounding `%`. For example, in the expression

```
x (%x. x (%y.xz)) (%y.x)
```

there are 5 occurrences of `x`.  The first is "free".  The second is the parameter for the `%` expression and is never substituted for. The third and fourth occurrences refer to the parameter of the enclosing `%` expression.  The fifth is free.  Therefore if we substitute `0` for `x` we get `0 (%x. x (%y.xz)) (%y.0)`.

All I need to use is pattern-matching and recursion. All I was able to write is the function prototype as

```
subst :: Id -> Exp -> Exp -> Exp
subst x (App z z') (App e e') =
```

If somebody could give me a hint how to implement the function it would be great. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: We'll be able to give better hints if you show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: One uses to pattern matching to examine the possible cases (abstraction, application, ...). When doing `subst x e1 e2`, do we really need to consider the cases for `e1`? And for `e2`? Once you decide which is the interesting one to consider, you will need one equation for every case (look at the definition of `Exp`).

Comment: @chi well, I understand that I need to use recursion to check whether each variable in expression e2 is free and if it's free and it's x we substitute it by e1. I just don't really understand how to implement it with recursion in haskell

Comment: Lambda calculus is actually rather subtle if you're going to do it properly, because of variable shadowing: what if you try to subst `y` instead of `0` in your example? You then need to rename the variable `y` in the original expression.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to first point out that the pattern matching (`subst x (App z z') (App e e')`) is non-exhaustive. (Most of) the other patterns are trivial, so it's easy to forget them. I'd suggest against pattern matching the third argument, because if all you're doing is subsituting it into the second argument, you don't care if it's an `App`lication or `Nat`ural.

The first step in most recursive functions is to consider cases. What's the base case? In this situation, it's where the second argument is equal to `Var x`:

```
-- Replace x with y in a Var. If the Var is equal to x, replace
-- otherwise, leave alone.
subst x (Var a) y
    | a == x    = y
    | otherwise = (Var a)
```

Then we need to consider the step cases, what if it's an application, and what if it's a lambda abstraction?

```
-- Replace x with y in an application. We just need to replace
-- x with y in z and in z', because an application doesn't
-- bind x (x stays free in z and z').
subst x (App z z') y = (App new_z new_z')
    where new_z  = -- Recursively call subst here.
          new_z' = -- And recursively call subst here, too.

-- Replace x with y in a lambda abstraction. We *do* need to
-- check to make sure that the lambda doesn't bind x. If the
-- lambda does bind x, then there's no possibility of x being
-- free in e, and we can leave the whole lambda as-is.
subst x (Lam z e) y
    | z == x    = (Lam z e)
    | otherwise = (Lam z new_e)
                  where new_e = -- Recursively call subst here.
```

Finally, all the trivial cases are the same (we leave alone both Nat and Op, since there's no chance we would be substituting them):

```
subst :: Id -> Exp -> Exp -> Exp
subst _ nat_or_op _ = nat_or_op
```

Comment: As Ørjan said, you do have to be careful about free variables in the expression you substitute in.

Comment: The `Lam z new_e` case can not be completed as it is. Consider `\x.y` where `y` is substituted with `(a (b x))`. The result should be something like `\z.a(b x)` -- note the fresh variable `z`.

Comment: @chi I'm strugling trying to do what you are saying (avoiding to capture variables). How do you select this new variable z? Would you have a  list of variables and pick the first one not used?

Comment: @arracso Yes. You need to generate a variable name which is not in use. Typically you compute the list of variables in use and choose the "first one" (according to some numbering) which is not there.